# Ajax created form element value is not available in chrome and FF

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

I have 2 select element in form. first select element is static and second select option change according to first select element.
for this i used jquery ajax. i am getting all things.
The problems comes when i submit the form. i dont get the second select element value.
**My code is working in IE.
But not in Chrome and Mozilla.**
My html file is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>DATA ENTRY</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>


  </head>
 <body>

 <table class="data_table">
<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="submit_ops.php" />
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="databaseTable" class="databaseTable">
            <option value="">Select Table</option>
            <option value="value1">value1</option>
            <option value="value2">value2</option>
            <option value="value3">value3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="TableColumn" name="TableColumn">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Continue" name="usubmit"/></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name^=databaseTable]").on("change", function(){
       var val=$(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {"val" : val},
            success: function(result){
                $("#TableColumn" ).html(result);

            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
 </html>
```

When i submit the form the value of TableColumn(second select element) is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#TableColumn` doesn't have a name attribute therefore its value is not submitted.

```
<td>
    <select id="TableColumn" name="TableColumn">
</select>
```

---

Your html is invalid(form as (direct)child of table), so the browser is trying to make sense of it and it ends up with your second select outside of your form. Use proper html to avoid this

```
<form ...>
   <table ...>
      ...
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: We post same answer at same time 17:38:22 :)

Comment: @aligarian try putting the form tag out side the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't assigned any name to second element, change it to:

```
<select id="TableColumn" name="second">
</select>
```